# How do I match a Russian word in Unicode text using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I have a website I want to regexp on, say http://www.ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/perl . The site is in Russian and I want to pull out all the Russian words. Matching with `\w+` doesn't work and matching with `\p{L}+` retrieves everything.

How do I do it?

Comment: This is exactly what Unicode properties are for. Use \p{cyrillic}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -MLWP::Simple -e 'getprint "http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl"'
403 Forbidden <URL:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl>
```

Well, that doesn't help!

Downloading a copy first, this seems to work:

```
use Encode;

local $/ = undef;
my $text = decode_utf8(<>);

my @words = ($text =~ /([\x{0400}-\x{04ff}]+)/gs);

foreach my $word (@words) {
  print encode_utf8($word) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Wikipedia seems to block LWP::Simple requests. It might work if you change the useragent string.

Comment: I think you meant `\x{0401}-\x{042f}` for russian words. No need to overly match characters. Check the unicode table [here](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Russian_alphabet)

Answer (score 4):

All those answers are overcomplicated. Use this

`$text =~/\p{cyrillic}/`

bam.

Comment: It should actually be

`$text =~ /\p{Cyrillic}/`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, then try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

my $response = $ua->get("http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl");

die $response->status_line unless $response->is_success;

my $content = $response->decoded_content;

my @russian = $content =~ /\s([\x{0400}-\x{052F}]+)\s/g;

print map { "$_\n" } @russian;
```

I believe that the Cyrillic character set starts at `0x0400` and the Cyrillic supplement character set ends at `0x052F`, so this should get many of the words.

Comment: Thanks that throwsw a warning: "Malformed UTF-8 character (overflow at 0x4043e433, byte 0xd1, after start byte 0xbf) in pattern match (m//) at retrieveFromWiki.pl line 45." and retrieves everything including english terms (in english characters)

Answer (score -1):

Just leave this here. 
Match a specific Russian word

```
use utf8;
...
utf8::decode($text);
$text =~ /привет/;
```